# Why I'm getting duplicate subdirectory store url in Magento?

Tags: magento, duplicates, subdirectory

I already have a working shop and wanted to create a new store using the same backend database and theme. So I created a new website, store and store view. The site is working ok. But in the case that the new website url should be eg:

http://www.domain.com/store/department/product

it appears:

http://www.domain.com/store/department/departament/product.

What might be happening? This is driving me crazy.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: is your new website in a subdirectory? what is the base url setting for this new website?

Comment: If your website is in subdir - look for `RewriteBase` directive in `.htaccess`. You should uncomment it and change accordingly to your subfolder name (there are you'll see instructions in comments).

Comment: Thank you Zyava! Your solution worked great. Now I got my two websites working. But I want to do one thing. I got www.domain.com/store/department1 and www.domain.com/store/department2. How can I do to when the user click on a product, the URL turn into www.domain.com/product-name? You can check the Zalando.de site as example. I think that I need to create some rules in .htaccess, but what?